# Extracting grayscale images from a video using opencv

Tags: video, grayscale, opencv, python

I am trying to extract images (frames) from a video and save them at a specific location. I have written the following code where it works well for extracting color images.

`extractFrames(srcPath,dstPathColor)`

However, When I want to extract grayscale image (`extractFrames(srcPath,dstPathColor,gray=True`), only one image is written to destination folder and code stops

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
print('OpenCV version: '+cv2.__version__)
import matplotlib as plt

def extractFrames(srcPath,dstPath,gray=False):
    # gray = true writes only grayscale images of the video
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(srcPath)

    # check if camera opened successfully
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Error reading video file")

    try:
        frameCount = 1
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if ret == True:

                if gray==True:
                    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    cv2.imwrite(dstPath+'grayframe'+str(frameCount)+'.jpg',gray)
                    
                else:
                    cv2.imwrite(dstPath+'colorframe'+str(frameCount)+'.jpg',frame)
                                
                frameCount += 1

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

            # if frame is read correctly, ret is True
            else:
                print("Can't retrieve frame - stream may have ended. Exiting..")
                break

    except:
        print("Video has ended.")

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    

vidName = 'scale_calib2.avi'
srcPath = vidName;
dstPathColor = 'Extracted Images\\Color\\'
dstPathGray = 'Extracted Images\\Gray\\'

#extractFrames(srcPath,dstPathColor)
#print('Finished extracting color images from video')

extractFrames(srcPath,dstPathGray,gray=True)
print('Finished extracting gray images from video')
```

Ouput:

```
Video has ended.
Finished extracting gray images from video
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem to be the naming bug. I used `gray` for both image container for gray scale images and boolean parameter in function `extractFrames`